# Labels doesnt work on Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, winforms, label

Im using Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate and Im trying to convert some images using a progress bar and two labels but the text of both labels is not shown and the program just shows the labels with white background.

[image]

p.s. The labels backcolor is "Control" (not transparent)

I have two forms 1st the "Main" form and the "ProgressDialog" form

in the main form when I click my "Save" button

```
//copy the filenames to a new array to sort them
string[] FileNames = openDialog.FileNames;
Array.Sort(FileNames);                

//create an instance of my progress dialog
ProgressDialog progress = new ProgressDialog(this, 100/FileNames.Length);
progress.ShowProgress();

//save all the files in the array
for (int i = 0; i < FileNames.Length; i++)
{    
    //call the SaveImage method 
    SaveImage(FileNames[i], 597, 412, Fill);

    //increase the progresbar and set the label text of the progress dialog to the filename
    progress.Increase(FileNames[i]);
}

progress.Close();//close progress dialog and re-enable the main form
```

...and  here the code of my "ProgressDialog" form:

Bar: name of the progress bar

Comment: name of the label with the image path as text

```
private Form SenderForm;// the "Main" form
private int Step; //value to increase in the progress bar

public ProgressDialog(Form sender, int step)//constructor
{
    InitializeComponent();

    SenderForm = sender;
    Step = step;
}

//disable cose button
private const int CP_NOCLOSE_BUTTON = 0x200;
protected override CreateParams CreateParams
{
    get
    {
        CreateParams myCp = base.CreateParams;
        myCp.ClassStyle = myCp.ClassStyle | CP_NOCLOSE_BUTTON;
        return myCp;
    }
}

//re-enable the "Main" form
private void ProgressDialog_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    SenderForm.Enabled = true;
    SenderForm.Activate();//activate form
} 

//increase the value of the progressbar
public void Increase( string comment=null, int step=0)
{
    //if step is 0 -> use the Step of the constructor
    if (step==0) step = Step;

    //if the comment (the current file name) is != of null
    if (comment!=null)
        Comment.Text = comment;//use the comment of the parameter

    //increase progressbar
    Bar.Value += step;            
}

//show "ProgrssDialog" form
public void ShowProgress()
{
    this.Show();
    SenderForm.Enabled = false;//disable the main form
}
```

Comment: I can confidently state that labels work just fine in Visual Studio 2010.  Therefore, the problem must be with your program.  What does the code look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It happens because mainthread is too busy to update label in ui 
U should do the process in a thread to prevent the UI hangs
Have look to this post[C# question on preventing GUI from becoming sluggish when using backgroundworker/thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2249599/c-sharp-question-on-preventing-gui-from-becoming-sluggish-when-using-backgroundw)

Comment: You Are right ,but my experience tells me Its common problem when we are going to show user the progress of background Job

Comment: Yup.  The only mystery is why the ProgressBar *does* update.  Because it was made for cases like this, it automatically calls Update() when you change the Value property.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the font-color is also white. Try changing that or the background color of the labels to see if the text shows up.

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint where you set the label text to ensure you're actually doing that? Another thought - I ran into a case once where two system-colors which were supposed to be different actually weren't. Try explicitly changing colors to something you KNOW